# Django: Can a middleware signal listener manipulate a request object?

Tags: django, django-signals, django-middleware

So basically, I want a middleware to connect a signal listener that adds stuff to the request object. This information can then be included in a response. I currently have this:

```
class SomeMiddleware:
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.signals_received = ["I can see this"]

        def listener(sender, **kwargs):
            print "I can see this too"
            request.signals_received.append("I can't see this")

        some_signal.connect(listener)

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        response.write(request.signals_received)
        return response
```

The problem is, I can't see stuff I append in the listener. What up with that?

*Ultimately, the listener should register parallel tasks which may or may not be done in time to add them to the response just before rendering.*

**edit** - quotes in snippet

Comment: Are you saying that, in `process_response()`, `request.signals_received` is `["I can see this"]`? Do you get any exception? If you don't need to access `request.signals_received` from other points, I'd just store in an attribute of the middleware class itself

Comment: I tested this using the django shell and I don't get any exceptions at all. I would like to be able to have access to `request.signals_received` elsewhere, but I can probably work around that with careful ordering of middleware.

Comment: This is a very interesting and unusual use case. I'm interested in learning more details about why you need this set up in this way.